# Pan tilt zoom camera

Tags: camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, I'm working on a research on robot vision with a robot platform of Pioneer 2DX run in ROS. Would you like to introduce me some models of pan tilt zoom camera priced around $1500? My OS is Ubuntu 11.10. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12136/pan-tilt-zoom-camera/) by [MichaelHsu170](https://answers.ros.org/users/1367/michaelhsu170/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2011-11-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera_drivers) is a list of supported cameras in ROS. Additionally, there exist camera drivers for other types of camera. For example, my company uses the [Axis 214](http://www.axis.com/files/datasheet/ds_214ptz_33006_en_0809_lo.pdf) PTZ camera. It's a network camera with pan/tilt/zoom and also with audio capabilities. It provides 704x576 maximum resolution at 60 fps. It also comes with its own programming API to control the pan-tilt-zoom. Drivers can be found [here](http://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?name=axis_camera).

**EDIT:** All Axis cameras provide a control API known as Vapix. This is a HTTP-based programming library. You essentially send web-scripts to the HTTP server that's running on the camera. The camera then returns a message that expresses success or failure, etc. To program with ROS, you'd need to convert ROS commands to simple Vapix messages, send them over UDP, and then parse the response into ROS-readable format. I think the Axis 214 uses Vapix 2.0, but I'm not entirely sure. Google will tell you for sure.

As for mounting the Kinect on the camera, I don't see a reason that you *couldn't* do that. It would certainly look interesting to say the least. You'd just have to be careful to leave room for the camera to rotate properly, but that shouldn't be difficult.

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2011-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MichaelHsu170](https://answers.ros.org/users/1367/michaelhsu170/) on 2011-12-01**:
Thank you very much~

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2011-12-01**:
The pan joint certainly could. The tilt joint could be possible. I'm not sure what the Kinect weighs, so it's difficult to judge.

**Comment by [MichaelHsu170](https://answers.ros.org/users/1367/michaelhsu170/) on 2011-11-30**:
Thank you for your edit. For it is not designed for Axis 214 to mount something on it, I'm not sure whether motors inside are powerful enough to drive both the camera lens and Kinect, so there was the second question~ :-D Anyway, Thanks a lot~

**Comment by [MichaelHsu170](https://answers.ros.org/users/1367/michaelhsu170/) on 2011-11-29**:
Thanks a lot. I've some questions about Axis 214, though. 1. Does its api work under Ubuntu / Linux? I found that their website only mentioned for Windows developers. 2. Do you think it is possible to mount a Kinect sensor on the top of Axis 214 to make the Kinect sensor pan tilt with 214? Thank you

**Comment by [piyushk](https://answers.ros.org/users/1770/piyushk/) on 2013-01-27**:
There is an axis camera driver in ROS: http://ros.org/wiki/axis_camera

**Comment by [Jose Luis](https://answers.ros.org/users/3057/jose-luis/) on 2014-10-30**:
Is possible to get audio from the Axis Camera with Ubuntu + ROS?